# How to select what LAN port to use with VNC, ping, or another apps?

Tags: windows, vpn

See image to get info how is my network built:
[image: network schematics]

I do have office network 192.168.1.0/24 connected through router/NAT to internet. My PC has TWO LAN ports: the main has address 192.168.1.50, and the second one 192.168.10.50. The second LAN is 192.168.10.0/24 with some testing devices.

Customer site has network 192.168.10.0/24 with some devices. Customer site has router with VPN server. I do have VPN client on my PC. So I can establish VPN connection and I can ping devices in customer's LAN.
(Note: VPN Server/router is realized by HW eWon; I use eCatcher VPN client on my PC.)

I can be simultaneously connected to remote 192.168.10.0/24 LAN (through VPN) and locally to 192.168.10.0/24 LAN (through second LAN port) without any problems/collisions.

My service application that connects to devices is able to select what interface to use for connection (whether the first or the second LAN port) - so I can connect to device in remote LAN and in local LAN too, although the devices have same addresses.

So far so good.

(Note: If I travel to customer site I switch my primary LAN port to 192.168.10.50 and I connect directly to customers LAN.)

Important note: I need to have all devices (both in customer LAN and i my local devices LAN the same subnet address 192.168.10.x) because it would be very complicated to change IP adresses in my development software.... take it simply as is. No way to change it !!!

And now the problem to solve: if I use another application software like VNC, or I ping remote device, it always connect to remoted device through VPN. I can't select what port to use so I can't VNC, ping, etc to the local 192.168.10.0/24 network. Applications always select the main LAN port.
Any idea how to solve it ???

Comment: +1 for the awesome sketch. Alone drawing this shows more effort than most questions.

Comment: The path to any IP address is determined by routing. When there's an address collision you can only connect to one of the subnets, determined by the more specific routing table entry (=longer prefix) or, when tied, by the metric.

Answer (score 1):

If changing your local network to another subnet that is less prone to collisions is not an option there is not much you can do.

The ability to select an outgoing IP address needs to be implemented in the application, some provide it, some don't.

- the windows `ping` command provides the argument `-S`

  > -S srcaddr     Source address to use.
- The Powershell cmdlet [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection#-constraininterface) provides the arguments `-ConstrainInterface` and `-ConstrainSourceAddress`
- VNC ... there are too many implementations to list. You may be able to find one that allows to set a source address.

---

Another option might be to set up a container or a VM for your software that can be routed to the interface of your choice.

---

Third option: Set up a router on your network with a different subnet where you can plug your machine into while you are connected to VPNs with colliding subnets.

Answer (score 0):

> I can be simultaneously connected to remote 192.168.10.0/24 LAN (through VPN) and locally to 192.168.10.0/24 LAN (through second LAN port) without any problems/collisions.

You can't - as you have seen. You don't get any error messages, but most applications doesn't care about network cards; they care about IP addresses, and lets the operating system handle routing decisions. Some applications can set the source IP, but many can't.

In Linux you could solve it using [network namespaces](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/network_namespaces.7.html), but I'm not aware of such a feature on Windows.

This leaves you with a few alternatives:

- Use a VM that is not aware of your LAN on 192.168.10.0/24.
- Make your VPN server perform NAT so that 192.168.10.0/24 appears as something else.
- Readdress one (or both) of the networks so that you have unique ranges.

VM and NAT is probably the easiest and quickest configurations, but NAT is a cludge that may come back to haunt you later.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a split vpn configuration, where you specify which network gets routed over the VPN

If you can I would create a small subnet for the vpn and using ip routing forward that over a interface which connects to the VPN. Then you stay connected to the VPN and still reach workloads in your home network

For example assign 10.0.0.1 to the network adapter that connects to the VPN, and then change the routing table that only that network is routed over the VPN

Another option would be get a router with openwrt or something like that and connect to the VPN directly from the router with openvpn, and then also update the Routing table that only that network is routed over the VPN

But this is all client vpn a more ideal situation would be a site to site vpn where you create a vpn to a whole network. You might need a advanced network appliance for that, a small Linux device would also work